# Archive comment w/o moving to spam/trash

Tags: comments

How can I archive a comment so that it doesn't appear new, without 
moving it to spam or trash?

The comment is interesting, so I want to keep it for myself, but not 
approve it.

Comment: how about just marking it with a different status and have a custom page under comments (does it allow?) to show archived comments. You will just need a button along with others to mark its status to a value not used and which will not be used by some other thing to save its status. Just an idea, never really did anything similar.

Comment: @Ashfame That would be my ideal solution. However, I can't find a way to add more statuses to a comment. There doesn't even seem to be a plugin that does that.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet might be simply to leave the comment in the moderation queue?

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but it's annoying because it keeps telling me I have 1 "unseen" comment. I want to store it away safely, but not see if every time I moderate comments.

Answer (score 1):

On my blog we want to keep the comments that wont pass moderation as a record of offending text. In the end we added

```
define('EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 100000);
```

to wp-config.php and move everything to trash. Yes in 273 years it will start deleting them, but it's a trade off we went for.

Comment: I dislike using the trash for anything other than trash. It seems "easy" (to someone who doesn't have to do it <G>) to add more statuses for comments?